# Не отображается имя пользователя

Tags: php, сессия

В странице не отображется имя пользователя. Когда юзер авторизуется, его имя передается в сессию. Сессия включены в начале файла, в обоих страницах: `session_start()`.

**index.php**:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) : ?>
You're logged in.<br>
Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; ?>
```

**login.php**:

```
$_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
```

Comment: А в переменной `$user` хранится строка с именем пользователя? Если да, то стоит убрать `->login;`

Comment: @iEPCBM $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Стоит использовать `serialize()` при добавлении объектов к `$_SESSION` и `unserialize()` при их извлечении:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) : ?>
You're logged in.<br>
Hi, <?php echo unserialize($_SESSION['logged_user'])->login; ?>
```

```
$_SESSION['logged_user'] = serialize($user);
```

Подробнее см.: [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) и [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Если нет необходимости сохранять тип объекта, лучше использовать json_encode и json_decode на порядок быстрее.